# The same swift app generates different images from one video on emulator and on a real device. generateCGImagesAsynchronously

Tags: swift, cgimage, avurlasset, avassetimagegenerator

The same app generates different images from one video on emulator and on a real device

```
assetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
assetImageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = CMTime.zero
assetImageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = CMTime.zero
assetImageGenerator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: times){rTime,image,aTime,_,error in
    savePNG(image, url)
}
....
static func savePNG(_ image: CGImage, url: CFURL, properties: CFDictionary? = nil) {
    guard let myImageDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypePNG, 1, nil) else { return }
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(myImageDest, image, properties)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(myImageDest)
}
```

Here is the python code that I use to compare images
[image: Result]

The result CGImage has different BitmapInfo. I'm trying to change simulator result to bitmapinfo like the device result.

```
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
let ctx = CGContext(data: nil,
                    width: image.width,
                    height: image.height,
                    bitsPerComponent: image.bitsPerComponent,
                    bytesPerRow: image.bytesPerRow,
                    space: image.colorSpace ?? colorSpace,
                    bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!
ctx.draw(image, in: bounds)
let resultCGimage = ctx.makeImage()
```

But it doesn't affect